# Spark Scala Cumulative Unique Count by Date

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, grouping, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe that gives a set of id numbers and the date at which they visited a certain location and I’m trying to find a way in spark scala to get the number of unique people (“id”) that have visited this location on or before each day so that one id number won’t be counted twice if they visit on 2019-01-01 and then again on 2019-01-07 for example.

```
df.show(5,false)

+---------------+
|id  |date      |
+---------------+
|3424|2019-01-02|
|8683|2019-01-01|
|7690|2019-01-02|
|3424|2019-01-07|
|9002|2019-01-02|
+---------------+
```

I want the output to look like this: where I groupBy(“date”) and get the count of unique id’s as a cumulative number.  (So for example: next to 2019-01-03, it would give the distinct count of id’s on any day up to 2019-01-03)

```
+----------+-------+
|date      |cum_ct |
+----------+-------+
|2019-01-01|xxxxx  |
|2019-01-02|xxxxx  |
|2019-01-03|xxxxx  |
|...       |...    |
|2019-01-08|xxxxx  |
|2019-01-09|xxxxx  |
+------------------+
```

What would be the best way to do this after df.groupBy("date")

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the ROW_NUMBER() function in this scenario. I have created a dataframe

```
val df = Seq((1,"2019-05-03"),(1,"2018-05-03"),(2,"2019-05-03"),(2,"2018-05-03"),(3,"2019-05-03"),(3,"2018-05-03")).toDF("id","date")

df.show

+---+----------+
| id|      date|
+---+----------+
|  1|2019-05-03|
|  1|2018-05-03|
|  2|2019-05-03|
|  2|2018-05-03|
|  3|2019-05-03|
|  3|2018-05-03|
+---+----------+
```

ID represents a person id in your case that can appear against multiple dates.

Here is the count against each date.

```
df.groupBy("date").count.show

+----------+-----+
|      date|count|
+----------+-----+
|2018-05-03|    3|
|2019-05-03|    3|
+----------+-----+
```

This shows the repetitive count of id's against each date. I have used 3 id's in total and each date has a count of 3 that means all id's are counted explicitly in each date.

Now to my understanding you want an ID to be counted only once against any date (depends if you want latest date or oldest date).

I am going to use latest date for every ID.

```
val newdf = df.withColumn("row_num",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"date".desc)))
```

Above line will assign row numbers against every ID for each date against it's entry, and row number 1 will refer to the latest date of each ID, now you take count against each ID where row number is 1. That will result in single count of every ID (Distinct).

Here is the output , I have applied filter against row number and you can see in output that the dates are latest i.e in my case 2019.

```
newdf.select("id","date","row_num").where("row_num = 1").show()

+---+----------+-------+
| id|      date|row_num|
+---+----------+-------+
|  1|2019-05-03|      1|
|  3|2019-05-03|      1|
|  2|2019-05-03|      1|
+---+----------+-------+
```

Now i will take count on NEWDF with same filter which will return date wise count.

```
newdf.groupBy("date","row_num").count().filter("row_num = 1").select("date","count").show

+----------+-----+
|      date|count|
+----------+-----+
|2019-05-03|    3|
+----------+-----+
```

Here total count is 3 which excludes ID's on previous dates, previously it was 6 (because repetition of id in multiple date)

I hope it answers your questions.